# Getting 200 Instead of 201 Status Code When Posting to WordPress with Python (Rest API)

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to create posts on my WordPress website via Python using the below code, but the `response.json()` just returns a `200` and a list of all the existing posts on my site in JSON format, i.e.:

> [{'id': 1,
> 'date': '2023-07-15T17:46:24',
> 'date_gmt': '2023-07-15T17:46:24',
> 'guid': {'rendered': 'http://1234.5.6.7/?p=1'},
> 'modified': '2023-07-24T03:58:06',
> 'modified_gmt': '2023-07-24T03:58:06',
> 'slug': 'slug',
> 'status': 'publish',
> 'type': 'post',
> 'link': 'https://www.example.com/2023/07/15/slug/',
> 'title': {'rendered': 'Title'},
> 'content': {'rendered': '\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\te',
> 'protected': False},
> 'excerpt': {'rendered': 'Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!\n',
> 'protected': False},
> 'author': 1,
> 'featured_media': 3957,
> 'comment_status': 'open',
> 'ping_status': 'open',
> 'sticky': False,
> 'template': '',
> 'format': 'video',
> 'meta': {'footnotes': '',
> 'csco_singular_sidebar': '',
> 'csco_page_header_type': '',
> .........

This my python code:

```
import requests


# Set the URL of the WordPress REST API.
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'

# Set the username and password for your WordPress account.
username = 'UserNameHere'
password = 'MyPasswordHere'

# Create a JSON object that contains the post data.
post_data = {
    'title': 'My First Post',
    'content': 'This is my first python post!',
    'status': 'publish'
}


# Add the authorization header to the request.
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(username + ':' + password)}

# Add the Content-Type header to the request.
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

# Use the requests library to make a POST request to the WordPress REST API.
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=post_data)

# If the request is successful, the response will be a JSON object that contains the post data.
if response.status_code == 201:
    post = response.json()
    print(post)
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code, response.json())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the URL endpoint definitely the one for adding new content? It seems to be returning content, as `/posts` would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Here is what ended up fixing it for me.

1. change the url so it includes "wwww" -> 'https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
2. The Basic Auth header value should be base64 encoded:

```
import base64
credentials = base64.b64encode(f"{username}:{password}".encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {credentials}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting 200 errors you are hitting the *wrong* url that is probably a *proxy* to the wordpress site.

Make sure you have set your domain as the pages domain if you purchased one.

In order to troubleshoot the 200 error, change the password to something obviously wrong and try different urls until you go from a 200 to a 401. The means you landed on the right URL but have the wrong password. Then, make a **New** user admin account and generate another application password. Use the new username and application password and it should work. Reason why you need to make a new account is unclear to me.